# CSS: Changing style based on screen width

Tags: javascript, css

One one part of my website, there are 3 things: 2 pictures and one div. The width is 100% and the height is 14%. The images are set to 100% height in this area. I want the last div to auto-resize to the remaining amount. Here is the code:

```
<div id="header">
<img src="foo.jpg" class="logo">
<img src="bar.jpg" class="logo">
<div id="clock">
</div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#header: width: 100%;
height: 14%;
}
#clock {
position: absolute;
left: 75%;
top: 0.1%;
}
.logo {
height: 100%;
}
```

I want the last div to pick up at the end of the 2nd image no matter what. How can I do this?

I have considered using javascript, like

```
var img1=[w,h];//I know this
var img2=[w,h];//I will put the actual #s
var w=screen.availWidth;
var h=document.getElementById("header").style.height;
var realw1=(h/img1[1])*img1[0];
var realw2=(h/img2[1])*img2[0];
var remaining=w-(realw1+realw2);
document.getElementById("clock").style.width=remaining;
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("clock").style.width=screen.availWidth-(((document.getElementById("header").style.height/img1h)*img1w)+((document.getElementById("header").style.height/img2h)*img2w));
```

I would prefer only CSS, but I will use javascript if I have to.

Comment: you want the #clock div to auto resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `float:left` the pictures? What does you div#clock contain?

Comment: Hm... does a clock need autoresize? Or better: What clock is it?

Comment: this.prototype.irrelevant(); :)

Comment: Its covering up the image, that's why I need resize.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

This CSS hides the clock behind the logo, when resizing small enough.

```
#header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#clock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 75%;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: -1000;
}
.logo {
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you want to change the width of the clock, `#clock.left + #clock.width` should equal to 100% or less, to prevent `#clock` "break through" the right side of the `#header`.

If your images contain transparent areas, you need to add a wrapper with `background` set.

Comment: @yourface I've edited my answer, it kills the covering problem now.